# In xsl, is there a way to next a normalize-space call inside a sum?

Tags: xslt, whitespace, sum, normalize

I have an XML file that has a number of nodes, each of which contains a `<current-fine>` node. I need to sum these values but unfortunately they contain white-space so I end up getting NaN as the total.

Is there a way of achieving the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(normalize-space(node/sub-node/current-fine))"/>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to bend the spoon:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of 
         select="sum(node/sub-node/current-fine[normalize-space(.) != ''])" />
</xsl:template>
```

Just sum what you can sum =)